# SSL www works but not without

Tags: .htaccess, ssl

If I go to my website at www.xyz.com, the browser returns https://xyz.com. If I go to my website at xyz.com, the browser returns xyz.com. How can I force the browser to show https://xyz.com, when typing in xyz.com? I'm using the following .htaccess code.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*\.)*xyz.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*\.)*www.xyz.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://xyz.com/$1 [R]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `[OR]` rewrite condition flag (you can also combine the first two):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www\.xyz\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://xyz.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Jon Lin, the blank pages are now working when I use your code with this code.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R,L]
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```